# RTA field to display image in a VF page rendered as PDF

Tags: pdf

I have a rich text field called Signature__c that contains a JPEG image. This custom field is under Contact object. 
Now I want to display this image in a VF page which is rendered as PDF.

I used the following format:

```
<apex:OutputField value="{!PurchaseOrder__c.Contact_r.Signature__c}"/>`
```

where PurchaseOrder is a custom object that has a lookup field for contacts.

But I am unable to print the image into pdf. It displays blank.

Please kindly throw some light on this.

Comment: It is working now. i was referring to wrong field.

Answer (score 0):

If the Image that's there on RTA field is to be rendered on PDF, use :

```
<apex:outputText value="name of the field" escape="false"/>
```

escape="false" attribute considers the HTML tags as is and not as String.